# Why WebView sparkles when I make network request in background?

Tags: android, networking, webview, lag

I have an Android activity with the following layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity, I load ad in the onCreate method and loadUrl for my WebView like that :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // ad view
 adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);

 // Load webview with game
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
 webView.loadUrl("...");

 ...
}
```

After that, I use adView only in activity with following calls:

```
public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 adView.resume();
}

public void onPause() {
 adView.pause();
 super.onPause();
}

public onDestroy() {
 adView.destroy();
 super.onDestroy();
}
```

In my webview, I display just a static HTML page with no network request.

My problem is the following : it seems that sometimes (especially when adView is refreshed), the webview is sparkling without stop. When I remove adView, the webview doesn't sparkle.

Do you know, if there is a solution to prevent webview to have this behaviour when adView is refreshed ?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: Please post the the code, where you are loading the Url in background thread on your Webview.

Comment: There is no more code like that. Ad loading is realized by Ad framework so I don't have the hand on the load. For webview, I just made a loadUrl.